# Verbs for animal noises in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, animals

This is specifically about verbs not onomatopoeia.

I understand that you can say 「（動物）は（音）という」, e.g. 「犬がワンという」。But beyond that I've come to two words 吠える and 鳴く, which both seam to be generalised animal noised. I want help understanding these and to know if there are any more and what do they mean.

I've sorta come to understand 吠える is more of a loud shouting noise while 鳴く is more of a soft noise.

So am i right for the following:

Dog barks. (吠える [or 鳴く?])

Cat purrs. (鳴く)

Bird tweets. (鳴く)

Lion roars (吠える)

Wolf Howls (吠える)

Elephant toots (鳴く?)

Horse neighs (鳴く?)

Also I've also come across some other verbs:
さえずる (chirp) and さわぐ (make noise).

is さえずる purely for birds?

and i take it さわぐ has a negative connotation like mentioned in the other question i looked at?

What other verbs can be used to explain animal noises?

Related:
[Does 「鳴く」 give any nuances about the sound being made?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/does-%E9%B3%B4%E3%81%8F-give-any-nuances-about-the-sound-being-made/3247#3247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we usually say like...

犬が（ワンワン・キャンキャン etc.）吠える・鳴く

猫が（ニャーニャー etc.）鳴く・（ゴロゴロ）[喉]{のど}を鳴らす

鳥が（ピーピー・チュンチュン etc.）鳴く・さえずる （+ maybe 歌う？）

ライオンが吠える・[雄叫]{おたけ}びをあげる

狼が（ワオーンと）吠える・遠吠え(を)する

馬が（ヒヒーンと）いななく・鳴く

象が（パオーンと）鳴く

etc...

---

> Is さえずる purely for birds?

Yes, I think so... and you'd use it for pleasant/cute/lovely voices of birds. For example, you might say 「[烏]{からす}が（カーカー）鳴く」 but not 「烏が（カーカー）さえずる」.

> I take it さわぐ has a negative connotation...

Right, さわぐ is often used for noisy or unpleasant sounds (...but not always. For example, I don't think 「こずえが風にさわぐ」「木の葉がさわぐ」 necessarily carry a negative connotation).